# Unable to submit paragraphed text as a memo using a form in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm collecting data into an MS Access table using an Outlook-based form (Using the "Create E-Mail" feature in the "Collect Data" section of the "External Data tab" in Access 2010 ).

I've set several fields to Memo-style and enabled rich-text formatting. I've tried the following with both InfoPath and HTML settings.

When the form is opened in Outlook, it is possible to type paragraphs, insert bulleted lists, etc.

However, when the form is submitted, the bullets may be entered into the table, but the paragraph spacing is gone: only continuous line entry persists.

Is  there a way to preserve paragraphs when submitted a form to Access?

Answer (score 0):

did you try changing your datatype to Rich text instead of memo in access?

Comment: baradosa - I've set the Data Type to "Memo" and under Memo Settings (also in the "Fields" tab) I've selected "Rich Text".

Comment: that's Ok but Memo data type works just like text expect its more data.  If you set the data type to RichText (which is a separate data type in Access 2010) data will be encoded in HTML or XML which would integrate well with Outlook as it will send data back in HTML

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact I was looking for but it's a workaround. I can insert HTML directly into the response form, and that will come through to the Access table upon submissions. e.g: I can type

```
This is a line <br> This is another line <br> This is a third line
```

and it will appear as such in the MS Access table:

```
This is a line
This is another line
This is a third line
```

Works fine, and I'm OK using it, however I'm collecting memo data from 100's of casual users, I'm sure most of whom will not be interested in learning any HTML, even a simple bit like this. If anyone has further suggestions, please let me know.